# Replacing socket for Cat5 cable

Tags: wiring

My situation:

To start off, I will provide photos at the end of the post.

The Cat5 Internet cable comes through a wall and it ends at a socket which is currently laying on the floor. The output of that socket goes to the modem. However, the connection is supported only by two thin wires, which makes the entire thing really flimsy and it creates problems when connecting to the internet. I would like to make the connection sturdier by using a module (of some sort) and enclosing the entire connection in it. As it stands right now, I don't think it is feasible to connect the socket to the wall as the cable is coming in the room from a different point.

I would appreciate any help.

Entry point of cable in the room:

[image]

The old socket opening (before installing the new cable):

[image]

Input of the socket (with the two thin cables):

[image]

Output of the socket (wire to the modem):

[image]

Comment: If I understand, you've got a CAT5 cable coming out of the wall, then it's attached to the back of a wall-mount jack (that's the term you're after), but the wall-mount jack isn't actually mounted to the wall? Seems to me you just need to mount the jack to the wall with the 2 screws sticking out of if (you may need some sort of drywall or masonry anchor). Where does the first picture come in with the wire through a tiny hole in the wall & no jack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot make out from your low-resolution pictures if there's a strain relief or cable tie point built into the socket. Possibly the silver loops on the right side of the third picture? If so, using a cable tie to tie the cable to that would stabilize it. If not, attaching 4 of the unused conductors to the unused contacts will make a better mechanical connection to the cable. If the terminal strip has holes that go all the way through it, moving the wire connections to the "interior" side of that strip may also be helpful as opposed to making the connection on the "exterior" side as at present. Less interference when poking the assembly into a hole in the wall.

These fittings are normally simply installed in the wall, and once placed in the wall they do not move, so no further "enclosure" is needed. You can get "surface mount" boxes which do have a front and back that snap together, if you would prefer that.

While the 4-pair cable probably is Cat5, it is being used as a telephone cable, and is connected to a telephone jack. The only way it's "an internet cable" is via a modem running on the telephone line connecting to the internet. It is not any form of ethernet, despite sharing a physical layer that is used by ethernet.

Comment: The telephone line (via the Cat5) connects to the modem and to the internet. The surface mount boxes are the thing I was searching for, thank you for the help.